# Sharing transaction to more than one co- signers to get sign

Tags: horizon, stellar-sdk, multi-sig

I am very new to stellar. I have gone through the documents available in stellar offical website. In my scenario, trying to send the transaction to more than co-signers to get signature. wrote code using following link

https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-base/reference/base-examples.html#multi-signature-account .

now, how to send the transaction to respective co-signers parallely and get back to complete the transaction irrespective of  Convert the transaction to XDR string and float to the users for them to sign. User A will unpack xdr string to transaction and then sign it. Convert back to XDR string and then pass it to the next user and so on.

And can i know the exact use of @cosmic-plus/oc-multisig? can i achieve above concern using this library?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know You need to send the XDR one by one after each signer signs it. Or else you can decode the XDR that send by signers and get the signing part separately and integrate with you existing XDR.

Comment: can you define else part in detail?